# Adding hover message to choices in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, hover

I'm not a programmer which may explain why I'm having difficulty wit this task.

I created a survey on sharepoint and I want to add hover messages to some of the multiple choice options to explain what the options are about.
I would like to have different messages displayed when I hover on the options Natural, Technical and Economical. 
I tried editing the title below with the hover display message but it doesn't save.

Please let me know if it's possible.

[This is the part of the survey that I want to edit and different messages displayed when I hover on any of the Hazard types options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Cy3.png)

Comment: This is clearly non technical so the best for your scenario is something like whatfix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goyL6IejHsw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use jQuery tooltip.

Sample demo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('span[title="Natural"]').tooltip({
                content: "Natural Hazard"
            });
            $('span[title="Technical"]').tooltip({
                content: "Technical Hazard"
            });
            $('span[title="Economical"]').tooltip({
                content: "Economical Hazard"
            });           
        })
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I just have another question please. Where do I enter the code?

Comment: Insert script editor webpart into list form and insert the script into it,